# How to search through an array in AuthComponent::user()?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, authorization, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've been developing an application in CakePHP 2.6 where a staff member originally only belonged to one department however the system requirements have now changed and there is a HasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) relationship between Staff and Department.

This is now proving to be a problem where I show information to only those Staff who belong to a certain Department within a view as my AuthComponent::user() object now contains an array of Departments.

Is there an easy way to loop through the AuthComponent::user() Department array and check to see if a value matches up with a chosen value?

Old View code before HABTM relationship:

```
if (AuthComponent::user('admin') == 1 || (AuthComponent::user('department_id') == $department['Department']['id'])) {
    // Some code here
};
```

AuthComponent::user() array:

```
array(16) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["salutation"]=>
  string(2) "Mr"
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(6) "Joe"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(4) "Bloggs"
  ["email"]=>
  string(21) "joe.bloggs@email.com"
  ["role"]=>
  string(23) "Teacher"
  ["admin"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["dos"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["school_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["active"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["School"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "School Name"
  }
  ["Department"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["name"]=>
      string(20) "Careers & University"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "Geography"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "16"
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "ICT"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `Hash::extract` to extract the department ids, and then use in_array to check if your `department_id` is in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the easiest approach is to use [CakePHP's `Hash::extract()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::extract) method to build a simple array of all the departments belonging to the user and then checking if the department exists in that array like this:-

```
$user = AuthComponent::user();
$departments = Hash::extract($user, 'Department.{n}.id');
if (
    (int)$user['admin'] === 1
    || in_array($department['Department']['id'], $departments) === true
) {
    // Some code here
}
```

The Hash utility in CakePHP is well worth a look as it provides some very handy array manipulation methods that make working with the arrays returned by `find()` queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways you can do that. You could just write a function that loops through- and pretty simple to implement:

```
function doesBelongToDepartment($deptList, $userDeptId)
{
  foreach($deptList as $dept) {
    if($dept['id'] == $userDeptId) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And then you could use it like following:

```
if (AuthComponent::user('admin') == 1 || doesBelongToDepartment($department['Department'], AuthComponent::user('department_id'))) {
```